# Do a wait before .scr file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt

I have a simple .bat file to start a software, execute a .src with login and password, but the software takes long to start completly. How I can do a wait before executing the .src file?

The .bat file:

```
start /wait C:\Navis\Navis.exe /B "C:\Users\engenharia04\OneDrive\Dropbox\Coisas\CoisasCAD\AutoScript\Sistema Navis.scr"
```

the .src file:

```
    login

Passworld
```

Comment: Use `start "" /WAIT ...` (first quoted string might be interpreted as a window title unexpectedly)

Comment: Like this I get a error "No support for that interface" (translated from portuguese error) with the adress of the .src file.

Comment: any smarter solution instead of the "bat src"?

Answer (score 0):

#### How I can do a wait before executing the .src file?

```
C:\Navis\Navis.exe & C:\Users\engenharia04\OneDrive\Dropbox\Coisas\CoisasCAD\AutoScript\Sistema Navis.scr
```

> **Redirection**
>
> ...
>
> `commandA & commandB` - Run `commandA` and then run `commandB`

Source [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)